# How to programatically transfer files when there is "FTP Over ssh"

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, ftp, ssh

I am doing projects on ftp. On my client side they have ssh. Until now I done application without ssh, I don't know how to transfer files over ftp when there is ssh over
it.

I want to do it in C# 2.0. How to do it? Any information regarding this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You typically use the Secure Copy Program ([scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)), rather than ftp (or sftp).

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of documentation on Wikipedia, about the (non-)standard etc.:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol

However, note that there are alternatives: You can remotely execute "ls" using ssh and you can use scp to copy files.

If you really want to use sftp, my best guess for C# is to remote-control psftp.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you need a third party component for this, I've had good luck with [Chilkat's](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ssh-sftp-component.asp).